# AngularJs - json_encode returning nothing in certain cases

Tags: angularjs, json, cakephp, response

I'm using $http.get to get some information from the server. First the controller calls the BackendServices, and in the service i call $http.get:

Controller:

```
app.controller('courseController', ['$scope', 'BackendServices', function ($scope, BackendServices) {
    BackendServices.lookForCourses().then(
        function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        function (response) {

        }
    );

    $scope.addCourse = function (courseName) {
        console.log(courseName);
    };
}]);
```

Service:

```
app.service('BackendServices', function ($http) {
    var backendServices = {};

    backendServices.lookForCourses = function () {
        return $http.get('app/backend/lookForCourses');
    }

    return backendServices;
});
```

The PHP files works under cakePHP framework.

lookForCourses:

```
public function lookForCourses () {
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $cursosFind = $this->Curso->find('all', array('fields' => array('nombreCurso')));

    $cursos = array();

    foreach($cursosFind as $index => $curso) {
        $cursos[$index]['nombre'] = $curso['Curso']['nombreCurso'];
    }

    echo json_encode($cursos);
}
```

Doing this i get as a response on the console:

*Object{data: "", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}*

If I do this:

```
var_dump($cursos);
```

I get the following:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'nombre' => string 'Tecnologias de la informacion' (length=29)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'nombre' => string 'Propedeutico' (length=12)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'nombre' => string 'Lectura y redaccion' (length=19)
```

However, if i do the following:

```
$test = array(array('nombre' => 'Propedeutico'), array('nombre' => 'Tecnologias'));

echo json_encode($test);
```

I do get that array as a response...

What am I missing? I know this might be a silly mistake, but I haven't been able to solve it so far...

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: How about `echo json_encode($cursos, true)`?

Comment: Same result on the response like that... Object{data: "", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work doing a little modification, since the result of the request brings back a string with accents, example: "Tecnología", i had to utf8_encode each one of the elements like this:

```
public function lookForCourses () {
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $cursosFind = $this->Curso->find('all', array('fields' => array('nombreCurso')));

    $cursos = array();

    foreach($cursosFind as $index => $curso) {
        $cursos[$index]['nombre'] = utf8_encode($curso['Curso']['nombreCurso']);
    }   

    echo json_encode($cursos);  
}
```

Adding ut8_encode did the trick.